# opening html file with vba

Tags: vba

I have some .html files which I want to read with vba. I wrote this codes to do what I want but I get

> object variable or with block variable not set

error.

```
Dim arrListATA() As String
    Dim arrListTaskNo() As String
    Dim arrListDesc() As String
    Dim arrIssueNo() As String
    Dim arrIssueDate() As String
    Dim arrPartNo() As String
    Dim arrDMC() As String
    Dim arrApplicability() As String
    Dim arrDMCModelCode() As String
    Dim DMCs As String
    Dim arrSubTask() As String
    Dim subTasks As String
    Dim subs() As Variant
    Dim subs1 As String

   k = 0

   Dim objFile As Scripting.File
   Dim objFolder As Scripting.Folder

   Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
w = 0
m = 0
b = 0
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With fd
    fd.Filters.Clear
     If fd.Show = -1 Then
     myTopFolderPath = fd.SelectedItems(1)
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(myTopFolderPath)
    Dim arrSplitedDMC As Variant
    Dim arrSubTasks As Variant
        For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        Debug.Print myTopFolderPath & "\" & objFile.Name
        If Right(objFile.Name, 4) = "html" And Len(objFile.Name) = 33 And Left(objFile.Name, 8) <> "V2500-00" Then
            Debug.Print myTopFolderPath & "\" & objFile.Name
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=myTopFolderPath & "\" & objFile.Name
            Debug.Print "Opened"

            lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            taskCheckFlag = False
            myTemp = ""
            partNoFlag = False
            mySubTask = ""

            For i = 1 To lastrow
                txt = Cells(i, 1)
            Next i
```

My folder path and my object names like this

**C:\Users\ftk1187\Desktop\V2500 - Copy\V2500-00-70-72-02-00A-363A-D.html**

It's not opening my .html files. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: And on which line do you get the error?

Comment: I get error in this line `If Right(objFile.Name, 4) = "html" And Len(objFile.Name) = 33 And Left(objFile.Name, 8) <> "V2500-00" Then`

Comment: I don't see an obvious problem with that line if the `debug.print` above it works. Are you sure you have the right line of code with the error? Maybe try breaking up the if statement into just one check instead of 3 and see which part is returning the error?

Answer (score 0):

The code below actually runs.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Test()

    Dim arrListATA() As String
    Dim arrListTaskNo() As String
    Dim arrListDesc() As String
    Dim arrIssueNo() As String
    Dim arrIssueDate() As String
    Dim arrPartNo() As String
    Dim arrDMC() As String
    Dim arrApplicability() As String
    Dim arrDMCModelCode() As String
    Dim DMCs As String
    Dim arrSubTask() As String
    Dim subTasks As String
    Dim subs() As Variant
    Dim subs1 As String
    Dim objFSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim Fd As FileDialog
    Dim objFile As Scripting.File
    Dim objFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim arrSplitedDMC As Variant
    Dim arrSubTasks As Variant
    Dim myTopFolderPath As String



    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
'    k = 0
'    w = 0
'    m = 0
'    b = 0

    With Fd
        .Filters.Clear
        If .Show = -1 Then
            myTopFolderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
            Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(myTopFolderPath)
            For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
                Debug.Print myTopFolderPath & "\" & objFile.Name
                Debug.Print myTopFolderPath
                Debug.Print objFile.Name
                Debug.Print Right(objFile.Name, 4), Len(objFile.Name), Left(objFile.Name, 8)

'                If Right(objFile.Name, 4) = "html" And Len(objFile.Name) = 33 And Left(objFile.Name, 8) <> "V2500-00" Then
'                    Debug.Print myTopFolderPath & "\" & objFile.Name
'                    Workbooks.Open Filename:=myTopFolderPath & "\" & objFile.Name
'                    Debug.Print "Opened"
'
'                    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'                    taskCheckFlag = False
'                    myTemp = ""
'                    partNoFlag = False
'                    mySubTask = ""
'
'                    For i = 1 To lastrow
'                        txt = Cells(i, 1)
'                    Next i
            Next objFile
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

You will see that I added `Option Explicit` at the top and a few declarations that were missing. The variables k, w, m and b are also not declared but if they are numbers their value should already be 0 at that point of the code. According to my research, Excel should be able to open an HTML file but I wonder what it might show.

As a general piece of advice, I would recommend that you construct your code as one `Main`  subroutine which calls other subs and functions, each of them no larger than 10 to 25 lines of code. In your code you already exceed that number in your declarations. The effect is a construct that you can't control.